# Why can't MonoDevelop can't find the al2 linker to build satellite assemblies for ZedGraph?

Tags: .net, mono, monodevelop, satellite-assembly

System Info:

- Windows 7:
- MonoDevelop 2.4.2.1
- Mono 2.6.7

Trying to compile ZedGraph (a charting control).
But it has resources for multilanguage support which won't compile into a satellite assembly.

Please realize this all compiles, builds, and runs fine in .Net on Visual Studio. We're trying to port and get it all running on Mono.

Specifically, MonoDevelop gives an error that 'al2' can't be found which is the linker for Mono for .Net 2.0

My extensive googling on this simply resulted in learning that al2 is the linker for Mono .Net 2.0 and that it's supposed to be in the Mono distro.

So I installed the Mono distro and it shows the al2 in the bin folder.

But MonoDevelop still doesn't find it.

I suppose I could try adding the Mono bin to the Windows path but then I don't like adding to the bin due to incompatibility problems when building .Net using Visual Studio.

In short MonoDevelop builds great on all our in-house developed libraries. So how to get satellite assemblies working for ZedGraph project?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use xbuild to try again? http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build

It is not strange to see something compilable in xbuild failed in MonoDevelop, as xbuild is more compatible with MSBuild.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I got xbuild setup and although it failed somewhere else, it appears that it did pass the particular project in question. I'll fiddle with this and try to get xbuild to build completely first. Then circle back to see about MonoDevelop. It will help in the forums to show it builds in xbuild but not MD.

Comment: You can feel free to fire bug reports on xbuild and MD. Personally I think it makes more sense to report xbuild issues first, as that's what MD finally will use as build engine.